# console.log %o not printing object argument

Tags: javascript, node.js

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console the term `%o` should print out an argument as an object.

The following code:

```
var a = [34, 203, 3, 746, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];
console.log('myFunc(%o)', a);
```

Results in the output:

```
myFunc(%o) [ 34, 203, 3, 746, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9 ]
```

I was expecting:

```
myFunc([ 34, 203, 3, 746, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9 ])
```

*Workaround: Since %o is not a standard as Tusher pointed out and does not exist in node https://nodejs.org/api/console.html the following made the correct output:*

```
console.log('myFunc([%s])', a);
```

*robertkleps version also works:*

```
console.log('myFunc(%j)', a)
```

Comment: I'm getting correct output in latest Chrome. What browser you're using?

Comment: @Tushar Actually on Linux with Node v6.x

Comment: MDN says _Non-standard_

Comment: @Tushar Ah, knew I had missed something, post as answer I'll accept!

Comment: `console.log('myFunc(%j)', a)`

Comment: @robertklep Also works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using es6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var a = [34, 203, 3, 746, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];
console.log(`myFunc([${a}])`);

> myFunc([ 34, 203, 3, 746, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9 ])
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Very sexy indeed! I'll take it!

Comment: Pity you need to use ´ instead of ' or "